# Insert IGNORE with a multiple value entry statement; What happens on duplicate?

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

```
insert ignore into table (a,b) values (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2);
```

if `a` is `pk` or is a `unique` key, can I can reliably count on all statements NOT violating `pk` or `unique` constraint to be entered - even if they are AFTER the "violating" entry? i.e.: Do the non-duplicates get inserted and only the duplicates get "ignored" - no matter where they fall within the sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

I did more research and found this answer to another StackOverflow question:

[...and now some multiple row tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853634/263028)

Thanks to [Paulus Maximus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007660/paulus-maximus)